# Cannot use the method as a member not be called 'Match.Groups'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the special character of a match collection so I made this code:

```
MatchCollection SpecialCharacter = Regex.Matches(data, "\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})");

foreach (Match sc in SpecialCharacter)
{
   data = data.Replace(sc.Value, (char)(Convert.ToInt32(sc.Groups(1).Value, 16)));// ERROR HERE
}
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot use the method as a member not be called 'Match.Groups'.

on this line: `sc.Groups(1)` seems that if I put the `1` inside the brackets () the error appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is c# where arrays use square brackets not parenthesis,

Comment: Suggest you start local variables with lower case. `SpecialCharacter` is being highlighted as a Class/Method

Comment: @weston I changed it in camel case as: specialCharacter

Comment: Well, not in the question you haven't

Comment: @weston I mean in my code. A little question: I got `Cannot convert from string to char` on `sc.Value`, any idea?

Comment: `string.Replace` takes a pair of strings as arguments, or a pair of chars, but not one of each.

Comment: You have a `string` and a `char`, **you** need to decide which is wrong and should be converted to the other type. If you can't, then suggest you ask another question.

Comment: See in @un-lucky answer, he provides information on this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-member is a property, not a method. Thus use this instead:

```
data = data.Replace(sc.Value, (char)(Convert.ToInt32(sc.Groups[1].Value, 16)));
```

Where you enclose the index of the group with square-brackets.

When you come from VB you can use paranthesis for both as method-parameter and as array-index. In C# you have to use square-brackets for the arrays instead.

Comment: Oh, that mistake! A bit of confusion from VB.net, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Addition to the above answer: Sc.Value will be a string so you cannot assign a character value to a string. So you need to convert the character to string before assigning the value: The code will be like the following:

```
foreach (Match sc in SpecialCharacter)
{
     data = data.Replace(sc.Value, ((char)(Convert.ToInt32(sc.Groups[1].Value, 16))).ToString());
}
```